# How to display values that are less than a particular number in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I have created a model named Product containing these fields ('prod_name', 'company', 'quantity', 'price', 'units', 'prod_type')

I want to display those products in the webpage that have less than 2 units remaining
I tried using Model.Objects.filter(units__lte=2) but I am not getting the desired output

Here is my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView
from django.db.models import Q
from .models import *
from .forms import *

def get_stock(request):
   items=Product.objects.filter(units__lte=2)

   context={
     'items':items
    }

   return render(request, 'UpdateStock.html', context)
```

here is my urls file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns=[
   url(r'^get_stock$', get_stock, name='get_stock'),
]
```

here is my HTML file for the same

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

    {% block body %}

    <br>
        <h3>Update Stocks</h3>
    <br>

    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Sr. No.</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Units</th>
                <th>Product Type</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for item in object_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{item.pk}}</td>
                <td>{{item.prod_name}}</td>
                <td>{{item.company}}</td>
                <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
                <td>{{item.price}}</td>
                <td>{{item.units}}</td>
                <td>{{item.prod_type}}</td>
            </tr>


            {% endfor %}

        </tbody>
    </table>    

    {% endblock %}
```

But the results are not getting displayed

Comment: Less than, or less than or equal?

Comment: @Willemvanonsem less than or equal

Answer (score 1):

> I want to display those products in the webpage that have less than 2 units remaining I tried using `Model.objects.filter(units__lte=2)` but I am not getting the desired output.

The [**`__lte`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#lte) is a filter that filters for "less than *or equal*", this is what the `e` in `lte` means. You probably need to use the [**`__lt`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#lt):

```
Model.objects.filter(units__lt=2)
```